# grails config keeps changing

Tags: spring, grails

In my GSP I have the following code(as debugging)

```
${grailsApplication.config.myConfig.provider}
```

For the longest time I had in my config:

```
myConfig.provider='a'
```

I have completed the projet for provider a and switched it to b

```
myConfig.provider='b'
```

I have cleaned the project, even deleted my target folder, yet when I navigate to the page it still prints "a"

Comment: check, that you're not overriding the value by a) environment or b) on a later location again.  `grep 'myConfig.provider' **/*.groovy` for a start

Comment: I had a conditional with only 1 equal sign and my IDE didn't catch it because it's in a GSP...  Thanks!